# Why my url is not updating when I send filters from the form? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been creating a react app, and I've added filters. Now I was using `window.location.search` to update my URL but that was causing a refresh on a page, so the SPA was lost.

Now I've found out for method `props.history.push` and I've replaced `window.location.search` with it.

Now the problem: Data is rendering when the filter is sent, but URL isn't updated - it stays on only `/dashboard`. I've also noticed that I can't send a new filter - eg. if I put max price 20000, data is fetched, and if I want to add also the max price per square meter when I add that parameter, nothing is happening. Also, my pagination doesn't work because the URL isn't updated with the correct page(it's stuck on the first page).

So everything workes properly when I use `window.location.search`, but I would like not to refresh the page, just update the state of data and URL.

Here is my dashboard.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import Form from 'react-validation/build/form';
import CheckButton from 'react-validation/build/button';

import ArticleService from '../../services/article.service';

import { Pagination } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import {
  faArrowAltCircleDown,
  faArrowAltCircleUp,
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
library.add(faArrowAltCircleDown, faArrowAltCircleUp);

const Dashboard = (props) => {
  const form = useRef();
  const checkBtn = useRef();

  const parsedUrl = new URLSearchParams(props.history.push);
  const pageSearchParam = new URLSearchParams(props.history.push);
  const maxPriceSearchParam = new URLSearchParams(props.history.push);
  const minSqmSearchParam = new URLSearchParams(props.history.push);
  const maxSqmSearchParam = new URLSearchParams(props.history.push);
  const maxPricePerSqmSearchParam = new URLSearchParams(props.history.push);

  const filterNameInURL = parsedUrl.get('filter');
  const pageParam = Number(pageSearchParam.get('page')) || 1;
  const maxPriceParam = Number(maxPriceSearchParam.get('maxprice'));
  const minSqmParam = Number(minSqmSearchParam.get('minsqm'));
  const maxSqmParam = Number(maxSqmSearchParam.get('maxsqm'));
  const maxPricePerSqmParam = Number(maxPricePerSqmSearchParam.get('maxppsqm'));

  const [content, setContent] = useState([]);
  const [maxPrice, setMaxPrice] = useState(maxPriceParam || []);
  const [minSqm, setMinSqm] = useState(minSqmParam || []);
  const [maxSqm, setMaxSqm] = useState(maxSqmParam || []);
  const [maxPricePerSqm, setMaxPricePerSqm] = useState(
    maxPricePerSqmParam || []
  );
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const [page, setPage] = useState(pageParam);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [triggerUrl, setTriggerUrl] = useState([]);
  const [showFilterForm, setShowFilterForm] = useState(false);

  const showForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setShowFilterForm(!showFilterForm);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (filterNameInURL) {
      const fetchFiltered = async () => {
        const res = await ArticleService.filterByName(
          filterNameInURL,
          page,
          maxPrice,
          minSqm,
          maxSqm,
          maxPricePerSqm
        );
        const { count, rows } = await res.data;
        setTotal(count);
        setContent(rows);
      };

      fetchFiltered();
    } else {
      const fetchPosts = async () => {
        const res = await ArticleService.articles(
          page,
          maxPrice,
          minSqm,
          maxSqm,
          maxPricePerSqm
        );
        const { count, rows } = await res.data;
        setTotal(count);
        setContent(rows);
      };

      fetchPosts();
    }
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [filterNameInURL, page, triggerUrl]);

  const onChangeMaxPrice = (e) => {
    const maxprice = e.target.value;
    setMaxPrice(maxprice);
  };

  const onChangeMinSqm = (e) => {
    const minsqm = e.target.value;
    setMinSqm(minsqm);
  };
  const onChangeMaxSqm = (e) => {
    const maxsqm = e.target.value;
    setMaxSqm(maxsqm);
  };

  const onChangePricePerSqm = (e) => {
    const maxpricepersqm = e.target.value;
    setMaxPricePerSqm(maxpricepersqm);
  };

  const submitFilterData = () => {
    setTriggerUrl(minSqm);
  };

  const handleFilteredData = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    form.current.validateAll();

    setLoading(true);
    if (checkBtn.current.context._errors.length === 0) {
      try {
        onsubmit = () => {
          maxPriceSearchParam.set('maxprice', maxPrice);
          maxPriceSearchParam.set('minsqm', minSqm);
          maxPriceSearchParam.set('maxsqm', maxSqm);
          maxPriceSearchParam.set('maxppsqm', maxPricePerSqm);
          const addToURL = maxPriceSearchParam.toString();
          props.history.push = addToURL; //after user clicks on button "filter" it should update url
          setLoading(false);
        };
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    } else {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const render = (item, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td className='text-center'>
          <div key={item.id}>
            <img
              src={`${item.pictures}`}
              alt='pic of article'
              className='rounded'
            ></img>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td className='text-center'>
          <div key={item.id}>
            <h4>{item.descr}</h4>
            <br></br>
            <h6 className='text-left'>Number of sqm: {item.sqm}m2</h6>
            <div className='text-left'>
              <small className='text-left'>
                {' '}
                <a href={item.link} target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>
                  Show article
                </a>
              </small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td className='text-center'>
          <div key={item.id}>
            <h4>{item.price}</h4>
            <small className='text-left'>Price per sqm: {item.ppm2}KM</small>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td className='text-center'>
          <div key={item.id}>
            <Link to={`/article/${item.id}`}>
              <h4>Show</h4>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  };

  const capitalize = (str) => {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
  };

  const renderHeader = () => {
    if (filterNameInURL) {
      return (
        <h4 className='text-center'>
          Total number of articles {total} on request location - 
          {capitalize(filterNameInURL)}
        </h4>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <h4 className='text-center'>
          Total number of apartments is: {total}
        </h4>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='container'>
        {renderHeader()}
        <div className='text-center'>
          <form className='mb-1 text-center'>
            <button
              onClick={showForm}
              type='button'
              className='btn btn-dark w-100'
            >
              Show filters{' '}
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={
                  showFilterForm === false
                    ? 'arrow-alt-circle-down'
                    : 'arrow-alt-circle-up'
                }
              />
            </button>
          </form>
          {showFilterForm && (
            <Form onSubmit={handleFilteredData} ref={form}>
             Max price:{' '}
              <input
                type='text'
                className='form text-center mr-2'
                placeholder='npr. 120000'
                aria-describedby='basic-addon2'
                value={maxPrice}
                onChange={onChangeMaxPrice}
              />
              Sqm from{' '}
              <input
                type='text'
                className='form text-center'
                placeholder='npr. 50'
                aria-describedby='basic-addon2'
                value={minSqm}
                onChange={onChangeMinSqm}
              />{' '}
              to{' '}
              <input
                type='text'
                className='form text-center mr-2'
                placeholder='npr. 100'
                aria-describedby='basic-addon2'
                value={maxSqm}
                onChange={onChangeMaxSqm}
              />
              Max price per sqm:{' '}
              <input
                type='text'
                className='form text-center'
                placeholder='npr. 2000'
                aria-describedby='basic-addon2'
                value={maxPricePerSqm}
                onChange={onChangePricePerSqm}
              />
              <button
                onClick={submitFilterData}
                className='btn btn-dark btn-block mt-2 mb-1'
                disabled={loading}
              >
                {loading && (
                  <span className='spinner-border spinner-border-sm'></span>
                )}
                <span>
                  <i className='fas fa-sync-alt'></i>Filter!
                </span>
              </button>
              <CheckButton style={{ display: 'none' }} ref={checkBtn} />
            </Form>
          )}
        </div>

        <div className='table-responsive'>
          <table className='table'>
            <thead className='thead-dark'>
              <tr>
                <th className='text-center' scope='col'>
                  Picture
                </th>
                <th className='text-center' scope='col'>
                  Description
                </th>
                <th className='text-center w-25' scope='col'>
                  Price
                </th>
                <th className='text-center' scope='col'>
                  Offer
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>{content.map(render)}</tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='mb-5 text-center'>
        <Pagination
          totalPages={Math.ceil(total / 10)}
          onPageChange={(e, d) => {
            pageSearchParam.set('page', d.activePage);
            props.history.push = pageSearchParam.toString();
          }}
          activePage={page}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

**EDIT**
Here is where my routes are included (App.js):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PrivateRoute from './components/routing/PrivateRoute';
import {
  MDBDropdown,
  MDBDropdownToggle,
  MDBDropdownMenu,
  MDBDropdownItem,
} from 'mdbreact';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';

import Landing from './components/Landing';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import Register from './components/auth/Register';
import UserBoard from './components/UserComponent/UserBoard';
import AgentBoard from './components/AgentComponent/AgentBoard';
import InterestRate from './components/AgentComponent/InterestRate';
import AdminBoard from './components/AdminComponent/AdminBoard';
import Article from './components/ArticleComponent/Article';
import Dashboard from './components/ArticleComponent/Dashboard';

import { logout } from './actions/auth';
import { clearMessage } from './actions/message';

import { history } from './helpers/history';

const App = () => {
  const { user: currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [showModeratorBoard, setShowModeratorBoard] = useState(false);
  const [showAdminBoard, setShowAdminBoard] = useState(false);
  const [showInterestsBoard, setShowInterestsBoard] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    history.listen((location) => {
      dispatch(clearMessage()); // clear message when changing location
    });
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser) {
      setShowModeratorBoard(currentUser.roles.includes('ROLE_PM'));
      setShowAdminBoard(currentUser.roles.includes('ROLE_ADMIN'));
      setShowInterestsBoard(currentUser.roles.includes('ROLE_PM'));
    }
  }, [currentUser]);

  const logOut = () => {
    dispatch(logout());
    setShowAdminBoard(false);
  };

  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <div>
        <nav className='navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark'>
          <Link to='/' className='navbar-brand'>
            <i className='fas fa-home'></i> Welcome
          </Link>
          <div className='navbar-nav mr-auto'>
            {currentUser && (
              <li className='nav-item'>
                <Link to={'/user'} className='nav-link'>
                  Profile
                </Link>
              </li>
            )}

            {currentUser && showModeratorBoard && (
              <li className='nav-item'>
                <Link to={'/mod'} className='nav-link'>
                  Banks
                </Link>
              </li>
            )}

            {currentUser && showInterestsBoard && (
              <li>
                <Link to={'/irates'} className='nav-link'>
                  Rates
                </Link>
              </li>
            )}

            {currentUser && showAdminBoard && (
              <li className='nav-item'>
                <Link to={'/admin'} className='nav-link'>
                  Admin Board
                </Link>
              </li>
            )}
          </div>

          {currentUser ? (
            <div className='navbar-nav ml-auto'>
              <li className='nav-item'>
                <Link to='/login' className='nav-link' onClick={logOut}>
                  Logout
                </Link>
              </li>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className='navbar-nav ml-auto'>
              <li className='nav-item'>
                <MDBDropdown dropleft>
                  <MDBDropdownToggle caret color='dark'>
                    <i className='far fa-user'></i>
                  </MDBDropdownToggle>
                  <MDBDropdownMenu>
                    <MDBDropdownItem>
                      <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>
                    </MDBDropdownItem>
                    <MDBDropdownItem>
                      <Link to='/register'>Register</Link>
                    </MDBDropdownItem>
                  </MDBDropdownMenu>
                </MDBDropdown>
              </li>
            </div>
          )}
        </nav>

        <div className='container mt-3'>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
            <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
            <Route
              exact
              path='/dashboard?filter=:location'
              component={Dashboard}
            />
            <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
            <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
            <PrivateRoute path='/user' component={UserBoard} />
            <PrivateRoute path='/mod' component={AgentBoard} />
            <PrivateRoute path='/admin' component={AdminBoard} />
            <PrivateRoute path='/irates' component={InterestRate} />
            <Route exact path='/article/:id' component={Article} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is where in my article.service the URL is sent to the backend

```
const articles = (page, maxPrice, minSqm, maxSqm, maxPricePerSqm) => {
  return axios.get(
    API_URL +
      `s?page=${page}&maxprice=${maxPrice}&minsqm=${minSqm}&maxsqm=${maxSqm}&maxppsqm=${maxPricePerSqm}`
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you include all your relevant code? What is rendering your routes? Please also include the component with your `Router` and `Route` components.

Comment: @DrewReese i've updated the post right now

Comment: Hmm, seems you are mutating the history object, `history.push` is a function you call with the path/etc you want to navigate to, and your `path='/dashboard?filter=:location'` isn't correct, path params only work in the path part of the URL, not the query string. Since you render the same component (`Dashboard`) for the same path (`/dashboard`) you likely just need an `useEffect` listening to the path/URL update in your dashboard component.

Comment: `path='/dashboard?filter=:location'` is triggered only if from landing page users sends a location. Right now I've found out for `history.pushState()` wil that help me?

Comment: `react-router-dom` only considers the path part of the URL for route matching. As I said, both "declared" routes render the same component, I'm 100% sure the first `path='/dashboard'` route is rendering your dashboard always. No, just `history.push` with the new route as a string, or an object if you need to also send any route state with the transition, which I don't think you're doing.

Comment: What would you recommend me to do? I would like to keep when users gets on `/dashboard` keep just that but if any of filters are triggered, update it and send request to the backend. My filtering works, so data is sent to the backend because it is rerendering the page with new data, only thing that is missing is url.

Comment: If the page is working as expected then what needs to be updated in the URL? I guess I'm not understanding this part/aspect.

Comment: When I enter dashobard, the url is `localhost/dashboard`. Now part that is worken on `window.location.push` is that when i send filter, it updates the url eg. i send max price 10000 the url is then `localhost/dashboard?maxprice=10000` etc. That part is not working right now, and I need it to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228388/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-aldinho).